# Can I complete my F4 Family Visa application from USA?

Tags: usa

My family and I had applied for a USA F4 Family Visa. Before our Visa application was completed, I came to the USA with an F1 Student Visa. Now my family has completed their F4 Family Visa application and are in the USA. Can I complete my F4 Family Visa application from the USA? Can I convert my F1 Visa to an F4 Visa from the USA?

Comment: What do you mean by "my family has completed their F4 Family Visa application and are in the USA"? Were they already issued their immigrant visas, and already entered the US with their immigrant visas?

Comment: Who's the actual immigrant? F4 is for siblings of US citizens - are you the sibling?

Comment: What relationship do you have to these family members?